# How to withdraw a scheduled email sent with microsoft graph api?

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I use the below code. Now I would like to withdraw the email. How?

I tried to set the Id and then delete it. But it says "malformated Id". Also, I´m not sure if this would stop the mail.

```
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "Meet for lunch later withID?",
    InternetMessageId = "88dc8516-103a-7df2-2685-1ce9045941b5",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "doe@gmail.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
                ,
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = 
        new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage()
        {
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
            {
                Id = "SystemTime 0x3FEF",
                Value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5).ToString("o")
            }
        }
};

var saveToSentItems = false;

await graphClient.Me
    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Comment: If what you want is let the Recipients can't see the sent emails, then it's impossible since there's no such kind of graph api.

Comment: @TinyWang The email is scheduled, but not sent. For example schedule is set in 3 days. Now i decide tomorrow that i don´t want to send the mail.

Comment: The `schedule` is realized by ms graph api? Or you write a custom scheduled task to call the api? actually I didn't find any document which describing a properity that can set a scheduled mail-sending feature, so I think you should focus on your `scheduled task` but not the graph api to try to prevent a scheduled mail.

Comment: Look at the SingleValueExtendedProperties property in the code above. This works. Not sure what you mean with "scheduled task".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the email with a schedule you need to create a draft with a schedule.

```
 var email =  await graphClient.Me.Messages
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(message);

 await graphClient.Me.Messages[email.Id]
        .Send()
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
```

Now this returns the message object with the id. This id can now be used to delete the scheduled email.

```
   await graphClient.Me.Messages[email.Id]
            .Request()
            .DeleteAsync();
```